# How to convert a faceted table to a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created a table like this using the **R** command:

```
table(Medicine, choose, Period)
```

[image]

I need to make this table to some kind of dataframe so that I can use it in ggplot to make a chart. Is there any way?

Comment: You can use "library(plyr)" and "Count" function to give a dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest would have been to use `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(table(Medicine, choose, Period))
```

Unless you are asking for a specific outcome, and can express your desired output, I don't see why the good old `data.frame()` wouldn't cut it.

A faceted table:

```
xtabs(~cyl+gear+am, mtcars)

, , am = 0

   gear
cyl  3  4  5
  4  1  2  0
  6  2  2  0
  8 12  0  0

, , am = 1

   gear
cyl  3  4  5
  4  0  6  2
  6  0  2  1
  8  0  0  2
```

And wrapping it in `data.frame()` or `as.data.frame()`:

```
data.frame(xtabs(~cyl+gear+am, mtcars))
   cyl gear am Freq
1    4    3  0    1
2    6    3  0    2
3    8    3  0   12
4    4    4  0    2
5    6    4  0    2
6    8    4  0    0
```